# ¿Como abrir un formulario anteriormente creado en visual basic desde otro en Visual C#?

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Tengo una ventana inicial llamada "Principal" esta ventana esta creada en Visual Studio 2015 en C#, y otra llamada "Secundaria" creada también en visual Studio 2015 pero en VB, ambas ventanas están dentro del mismo proyecto.

En la ventana "Principal" existe un botón, que abrirá la Ventana "Secundaria" y cerrara la ventana "Principal" en el mismo instante de tiempo, esta acción se ejecuta bajo la siguiente instrucción:(Esta instrucción esta en C# y lo que hara es Ir de la ventana "Principal" a la ventana "Secundaria")

```
 private void ButtonIr_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Secundaria s = new Secundaria();
        s.Visible = true;
        this.Dispose(false);
    }
```

Estando en la ventana "Secundaria" existe otro botón denominado Volver, la función de este botón sera la de llevar de la ventana "Secundaria" a la ventana "Principal", y cerrar la ventana Secundaria en ese mismo instante de tiempo, el problema esta en que en VB no me reconoce la referencia de la ventana "Principal" como lo hizo en C# cuando introduje el código para pasar a la ventana "Secundaria" desde la ventana "Principal"; intente usar esta instrucción: (pero no me resulto útil para devolverme a la ventana "Principal" aunque si funciona para llevarte a otra ventana nueva)

```
 Private Sub ButtonVolver_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonVolver.Click
    Dim p As New Principal()
    p.Show()
    Dispose(False)
End Sub
```

Cabe destacar que el proyecto en general la primera ventana creada fue la ventana "Principal" en C# y luego fue anexado el proyecto en VB de la ventana "Secundaria", no se si eso influye directamente en las referencias o si no importa para nada.

Si alguien sabe que estoy haciendo mal o que instruccion me falta declarar en VB para que me reconozca la referencia de la ventana principal seria de mucha utilidad, y gracias de antemano.

Comment: No entiendo muy bien lo que quieres hacer. En la ventana Principal, cuando llamas a la secundaria, haces un dispose de ella. Luego,en la secundaria, donde tienes alguna referencia a la principal? No existe por ningun lado. No te sería mas facil mostrar la secundaria de forma modal y cuando quieras volver a la principal simplemente cerrar la secundaria???

Comment: Ese es el problema quiero hacer ese botón de volver a la principal pero no se como serian las instrucciones para hacerlo.

Comment: Para que me entiendas mejor, esa ventana principal es una ventana con varias opciones que cada una de ellas me va a llevar a un modulo de calculo, por ejemplo, en la ventana principal aparece algo como que: "Resolver sistemas de ecuaciones"  y existe un botón asociado que me va a dirigir a la ventana correspondiente para realizar ese calculo esas instrucciones yo las tengo y son las que escribí en C#, pero al momento de hacer la opción volver en VB no se como hacerla

Answer (score 1):

Yo te recomiendo que utilices formularios modales si tienes que tener el formulario principal siempre en ejecución. La cosa es sencilla,sería algo asi:

En tu formulario Principal tienes que hacer esto:

```
private void ButtonIr_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Secundaria s = new Secundaria();
    s.ShowDialog();
}
```

Y en el secundario simplemente cerrarlo cuando quieras volver:

```
Private Sub ButtonVolver_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonVolver.Click
    Me.Close();
End Sub
```

Comment: Me gusta tu idea, si la entendí bien es así, que la ventana Principal siempre quede abierta, y que yo pueda llamar los distintos módulos de calculo y cerrarlos sin tener el problema de hacer una referencia circular.

Comment: Efectivamente @E.V001. Es la forma standard de funcionamiento.

Comment: muchas gracias, y podrías ayudarme a saber si la respuesta que acabo de publicar, que es las lineas de código que estaban en tu respuesta con la linea de código que dejara inactiva a principal podría funcionar?

Answer (score -1):

También creo poder agregarle una linea de código para que cuando principal abra secundaria principal quede inactiva pero visible y que cuando se cierre secundaria se vuelva a activar principal, seria algo asi:

`private void ButtonIr_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Secundaria s = new Secundaria();
    s.ShowDialog();
    this.Enabled = false;
}`

y en las secundarias hacer que cuando se cierren activen de nuevo a la principal

Comment: **Primero**, si quieres añadir algo mas a tu pregunta es mejor que edites ésta y lo añadas ahi, ya que esto no es realmente una respuesta. **Segundo**, una vez que ejecutas `s.ShowDialog();` no es necesario que hagas nada mas. Al lanzar un formulario modal, el principal queda deshabilitado y no puedes hacer nada en el hasta que el secundario no se cierre. Asi que `this.Enabled = false`no es en absoluto necesario